# Scraping data from an open IE tab with C#

Tags: c#, web-scraping

My application has a feature that is designed to check if there is an Internet Explorer tab open with a specifc string in the URL and, if found, scrape the innerText values from specific elements on that page.

The following code is based on code that works for another part of my application whereby the data is contained within elements contained within an iFrame, however that is not the case in the feature in question (i.e. no iFrame involved). This code throws an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' exception when trying to display the innerText value of the requested element, presumably because it can't find the element.

```
SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new ShellWindows();

        foreach (SHDocVw.WebBrowser ie in shellWindows)
        {
            if (ie.LocationURL.ToString().IndexOf("MyPage.aspx") != -1)
            {

                mshtml.HTMLDocument currentTab = ie.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;

//The below line throws an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' exception.
MessageBox.Show(currentTab.getElementById("lblFoo").innerText.ToString());

break;
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, I'm new to web scraping so I'm aware this might not be the most up-to-date way of going about this. I know of HtmlAgilityPack however I've been unable to find examples of how to use it to search for elements (and extract their values) after searching for a specific url in the open IE tabs.

Comment: Probably because currentTab.getElementById("lblFoo") doesn't return an object. Check for existence first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "lblFoo" definitely exists in the source HTML of the tab I'm targeting.

Answer (score 0):

These links help you to automate Internet Explorer in various ways.[Link1](http://freesnippets.50webs.com/csharp.html) 
 [Link2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9683/Automating-Internet-Explorer)  [Link3](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b2b1c4a1-41b3-4682-8dbe-a28fc532acd4/using-c-shdocvwinternetexplorer-for-form-submitting?forum=csharpgeneral)